# In htop, I sometimes see lists of 64 processes, identical for all but the PID. What are they?

Tags: process

I've noticed this situation several times (but I'm not sure if it is always the same command).

I don't even know how to describe the lead-up to this situation, unless it is because of a detached script I've been testing which hasn't terminated properly...

The best I can do is present this image of `htop` (Tree view)... I've only shown the first few. There is a total of 63 subordinate entries (plus the 1 parent)... and t hey just sit there!

I'd like to know what is going on?... and is the "64" some kind of limit?

Whatever the case, it just seems bizzare to have 64 threads/processes "running"

**Update:**
I've just rebooted the system, and this time, the first thing I did was to check `htop`...
**console-kit-daemon** shows 63 threads...  so It looks like this may be a normal situation...  It still seems a bit strange to me... Does anyone know why there are so many threads for **console-kit-daemon** ?

---

[image]

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 60+ threads is a [bug[image]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/consolekit/+bug/148454) with [ConsoleKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit).

Comment: Thanks DoR... This has solved the "puzzle"... On the bug page, someone suggested to change htop's **settings** to not "display userland threads". I tried it, and it turns out to be the same setting as pressing **H**... However, because of this, I've now become aware of some of  htop's useful settings; eg. Showing threads in a different colour... Highlighting the basename... and I see that **kernel threads** can be toggled on/off too... So, as well as learning about *console-kit-daemon's* unusual behavioue, this new insight into *htop* is a bonus  :)

Comment: @Peter.O thank you! didn't know pressing `H` hides the userland threads

Answer (score 36):

Those are user threads (as opposed to processes), and you can hide them using the 'H' toggle in htop.  See this explanation in its man page:

> H    Hide user threads: on systems
>   that represent them differently than
>        ordinary  processes  (such as recent NPTL-based systems), this can
>        hide threads from userspace processes in the process  list.  (This
>        is a toggle key.)

Comment: I'd like to add that this is uppercase "H", not lowercase "h" (they are not the same in `htop`, as I'm sure Daniel knows, but maybe not everybody else).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I must say that I hadn't realized that they were "threads", but none the less, they each have a unique PID, and I wonder how on earth I manage to get 63/64 concurrent threads ....and why is there this apparent 64 ceiling (which I have seen and counted in at least one other situaton?.. any ideas about this? ... By the way.. when the image was captured, I had **nothing running** (that I know of) other than Nautilus and the Terminal and a few other standard "static" apps (eg, gedit and firefox)

Comment: @Peter.O - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/if-threads-share-the-same-pid-how-can-they-be-identified, good read.

Comment: is there a way to start htop with this setting? `--help` doesn't explain it :(