# Why am i having multiple (40 or 50) instances of game servers when i type htop?

Tags: 22.04, ram, cpu

Hi this is my first post, thanks for taking the time to view/assist.

Hypervisor: Proxmox
VM OS: Ubuntu (headless)22.04.3

Here is the issue.
I'm running a game server and noticed an unusual large spike in cpu and memory usage.

I took a look at the "task manager" via htop.  There are several (40 to 50) extra instances of all my game servers running all with their own PID.  No one is operating in the game servers at the moment nor have been.  All 40 to 50 services appear directly after executing the launch of the game server.  This is spiking my memory usage unnecessarily which is causing my homelab development to come to a halt while I attempt to solve and understand this issue.

End goal is to get these multiple sessions under control and mitigate future issues.  I've double check to make sure no scripts or scheduled events are running in the back ground, no systems subroutines (to the best of my knowledge). Any guidance or follow up questions are welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In htop, I sometimes see lists of 64 processes, identical for all but the PID. What are they?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17047/in-htop-i-sometimes-see-lists-of-64-processes-identical-for-all-but-the-pid-w)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yes and no, it definitely sheds light on the what/why for me.  I don't think I'm able to toggle it as I just check "top" to see then see it.  The no is why my CPU and RAM is spiking and i'm not sure why.

Lets say I have 60GiB of ram assigned to this VM and between 3 empty running non intensive game servers, 20GiB is being utilize when it shouldn't've even total up to that because of the restrictions I placed in the executable file.  

I don't understand why this is happening and I'm not sure how to mitigate it unnecessary usage of resources when something is not in use.